# Japanese ANSI character in CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, uft14

I have a csv file generated from Japanese source system. The Japanese character is shown as given below `¬¼ˆã—ÃŠíŠ”Ž®‰ïŽÐ ‘åã‰c‹ÆŠ`. I have changed file type to UTF-8 and also ETL setting to incorporate that but that is working on new data only. 
How can I change existing data in my table which shows characters like `‘åã‰c‹ÆŠ`.

Is it possible to get original Japanese characters using SQL functions. I am using SQL Sever as database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you stored the data in the table already that is what you have. You can't go back later and magically restore data that was changed.

Comment: If you export your data into a file and change the encoding of old text, what do you see?

Comment: I am not able to see Japanese character by changing encoding of text file.